# How to set the app language in android within a service? (FirebaseMessagingService)

Tags: java, android

I am building an app, in which you can change the language of the app, independent of your phone/tablet language. It is working well inside activities, but it is not working inside a notification service. I want to be able to show the notification to the user in the language, he or she, specified in the app.

Here is the code I use for setting the language in my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LanguageHelper.onAttach(newBase, "sr_ME"));
}
```

And here is the code from the LanguageHelper.onAttach method. This code is from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugMTnF1R3Io

```
public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String lang) {
    persist(context, lang);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, lang);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, lang);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    config.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}

private static void persist(Context context, String lang) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getResources().getString(R.string.shared_prefs_logging), MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(context.getResources().getString(R.string.user_default_language), lang);
    editor.commit();
}
```

It seems that attachBaseContext is doing nothing inside my service class which extends FirebaseMessagingService, becuase I always get the notification in the language of my device.

I will really appreciate your help.

Best regards!

Comment: Notification will show by system Launcher and the launcher use system language. so you can't show notification in any language except system language

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could there be any workaround for this? I tried creating a string array like this: 

    `<string-array name="n_new_message_title">`
    `<item>Imate novu poruku</item>`
    `<item>You have a new message</item>`
    `</string-array>`

And then, when in onCreate of my service, I read what is the language user chose, save it in a variable. I create an array of strings ["sr_ME", "en"], and then find out which index to use, and than use the same index when selecting a string from string-array

Comment: Yes. I think this is only workaround. You should detect current system language and handle resources in that language by yourself. but it has a problem and that is you can't change direction of notification in RTL languages by default, and you should create your own notification layout.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase service and other services useds ApplicationContext, you should update configuration in applicationContext in onCreate() and in onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29818143)